# Rate limiting for creating new custom tokens for a user?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

My team is using Firebase Auth in our project. We're using custom claims to properly authenticate whether or not a user has access to a specific piece of information. We're storing each piece of information and deciding access for the user based off whether or not the user has access to a specific `location`. Each piece of data is somehow associated with a location, and we are storing the location id in the custom claims for the ID Token.

The problem is that a user potentially has access to thousands of locations. Instead of storing thousands of locations in the custom claims, we think it's better to generate a new custom token and exchange it for a fresh id token every time the user switches locations. That means that it's potentially reasonable for a user to generate a new custom token every few seconds as they switch through their locations if they are doing it quickly enough.

The Firebase Auth documentation doesn't indicate anything in regards to any rate limiting in this regard.

Are we going to run into any issues / rate limiting if a user switches through their locations very quickly? This would be unusual, but I just want to make sure that the worst case will still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control of Firebase Authentication custom claims is an Admin SDK operation and as such is not subject to rate-limiting. Firebase Authentication as a whole is designed to handle millions of concurrent users and is subject to various [rate limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits). Updating a user's custom claims would only contribute to the overall limits of 1000ops/sec and 10 million ops/day (at time of writing).

However, custom claims **should** be used for access control related data that will **infrequently** change such as the name of a role or a building ID. This is because the propagation of changed custom claims can take up to an hour and requires that the client code manually refresh their tokens after any changes to see an immediate effect. Custom claims have no mechanism to notify clients that they have been updated.

I'd reconsider your approach and store the list of locations a particular user has access to in the Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore rather than the ID token itself. You can then use this information to secure their access using appropriate Security Rules for those databases based on their user ID. By configuring a listener to that portion of the database, your client code can be instantly notified when a user gains or loses access to a new location. Additionally, you can poll information from multiple locations at once so you can show information in a notification feed or dashboard - something that can't be done with the claims strategy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You said "This is because the propagation of changed custom claims can take up to an hour and requires that the client code manually refresh their tokens after any changes to see an immediate effect." Our plan is to do a manual refresh.

This is the thought. Every time the user swaps their store, we validate access and swap their token, allowing access to that stores data. Bad idea?

Comment: @spierce7 It ultimately depends on your app design. If I was faced with your problem, I would opt for the database-based access control approach over token-based controls. However I am biased in that I deal with multi-tenant software often and get annoyed when I can't just switch tabs to view a different tenant. Imagine if you could only use one server in Discord at a time and how annoying that'd be.

Comment: "get annoyed when I can't just switch tabs to view a different tenant" - we can have multiple active JWTs though, each with different store information, right?

All our verification is done locally just be verifying the JWT.

Comment: @spierce7 It depends on if you are using the [`setCustomUserClaims` API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth.md#baseauthsetcustomuserclaims) or the [`createCustomToken` API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth.md#baseauthcreatecustomtoken). I think you need to clarify which one you are using as to my understanding, only the latter will work as you describe.

Comment: I was planning on the `createCustomToken` API.